# Scaling an object after rotating in SceneKit

Tags: ios, graphics, scenekit, scene

I am trying to set up a simple scene (one spherical node and the default camera) in a square SceneView.  Currently I set up the scene as below:

```
let scene = SCNScene()
let planet = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)
let planetNode = SCNNode(geometry: planet)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planetNode)
```

To *certain* views, I also rotate the node as such:

```
let rotationNode = SCNNode()
rotationNode.addChildNode(planetNode)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(rotationNode)
rotationNode.rotation = (SCNVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: some_amount_of_radians))
```

What I noticed, however, is the objects that get rotated are smaller than the ones that don't get rotated.  I am not really sure what the ratio is, but it seems to be dependent on how much rotation is added, to a point.

In the below screenshot, Earth is rotated 45 degrees, and the other 2 are not rotated.  If I rotated it 90 degrees instead, there is no difference, which leads me to believe there is a square bounding box around the sphere and the default camera is forcing its point of view to contain this box.

[image]

I have also tried to change the euler angles, position, and scale of the rotated nodes to compensate, but no transormations I apply seem to have any effect.  Any pointers for solving this camera issue would be perfect.

Comment: Have you set the debugOptions in your scene to see the pivot point of each sphere ? If the pivot point is not at the center of the sphere for whatever reason, that could explain what you see when you rotate.

Comment: @KarlSigiscar Nope, pivot points don't differ when changing the tilt of the planets